# GC overhead limit exceeded while training OpenNLP's NameFinderME

Tags: java, stream, garbage-collection, nlp, opennlp

I want to get probability score for the extracted names using NameFinderME, but using the provided model gives very bad probabilities using the probs function.
For example, "Scott F. Fitzgerald" gets a score around 0.5 (averaging log probabilities, and taking an exponent), while "North Japan" and "Executive Vice President, Corporate Relations and Chief Philanthropy Officer" both get a score higher than 0.9...

I have more than 2 million first names, and another 2 million last names (with their frequency counts) And I want to synthetically create a huge dataset from outer multiplication of the first names X middle names (using the first names pool) X last names.

The problem is, I don't even get to go over all the last names once (even when discarding freq counts and only using each name only once) before I get a GC overhead limit exceeded exception...

I'm implementing a ObjectStream and give it to the train function:

```
public class OpenNLPNameStream implements ObjectStream<NameSample> {

    private List<Map<String, Object>> firstNames = null;
    private List<Map<String, Object>> lastNames = null;
    private int firstNameIdx = 0;
    private int firstNameCountIdx = 0;
    private int middleNameIdx = 0;
    private int middleNameCountIdx = 0;
    private int lastNameIdx = 0;
    private int lastNameCountIdx = 0;

    private int firstNameMaxCount = 0;
    private int middleNameMaxCount = 0;
    private int lastNameMaxCount = 0;

    private int firstNameKBSize = 0;
    private int lastNameKBSize = 0;
    Span span[] = new Span[1];
    String fullName[] = new String[3];
    String partialName[] = new String[2];

    private void increaseFirstNameCountIdx()
    {
        firstNameCountIdx++;
        if (firstNameCountIdx == firstNameMaxCount) {
            firstNameIdx++;
            if (firstNameIdx == firstNameKBSize)
                return; //no need to update anything - this is the end of the run...
            firstNameMaxCount = getFirstNameMaxCount(firstNameIdx);
            firstNameCountIdx = 0;
        }
    }

    private void increaseMiddleNameCountIdx()
    {
        lastNameCountIdx++;
        if (middleNameCountIdx == middleNameMaxCount) {
            if (middleNameIdx == firstNameKBSize) {
                resetMiddleNameIdx();
                increaseFirstNameCountIdx();
            } else {
                middleNameMaxCount = getMiddleNameMaxCount(middleNameIdx);
                middleNameCountIdx = 0;
            }
        }
    }

    private void increaseLastNameCountIdx()
    {
        lastNameCountIdx++;
        if (lastNameCountIdx == lastNameMaxCount) {
            lastNameIdx++;
            if (lastNameIdx == lastNameKBSize) {
                resetLastNameIdx();
                increaseMiddleNameCountIdx();
            }
            else {
                lastNameMaxCount = getLastNameMaxCount(lastNameIdx);
                lastNameCountIdx = 0;
            }
        }
    }

    private void resetLastNameIdx()
    {
        lastNameIdx = 0;
        lastNameMaxCount = getLastNameMaxCount(0);
        lastNameCountIdx = 0;
    }


    private void resetMiddleNameIdx()
    {
        middleNameIdx = 0;
        middleNameMaxCount = getMiddleNameMaxCount(0);
        middleNameCountIdx = 0;
    }

    private int getFirstNameMaxCount(int i)
    {
        return 1; //compromised on using just 
        //String occurences = (String) firstNames.get(i).get("occurences");
        //return Integer.parseInt(occurences);
    }         

    private int getMiddleNameMaxCount(int i)
    {
        return 3; //compromised on using just 
        //String occurences = (String) firstNames.get(i).get("occurences");
        //return Integer.parseInt(occurences);
    }

    private int getLastNameMaxCount(int i)
    {
        return 1;
        //String occurences = (String) lastNames.get(i).get("occurences");
        //return Integer.parseInt(occurences);
    }

    @Override
    public NameSample read() throws IOException {
        if (firstNames == null) {
            firstNames = CSVFileTools.readFileFromInputStream("namep_first_name_idf.csv", new ClassPathResource("namep_first_name_idf.csv").getInputStream());
            firstNameKBSize = firstNames.size();
            firstNameMaxCount = getFirstNameMaxCount(0);
            middleNameMaxCount = getFirstNameMaxCount(0);
        }
        if (lastNames == null) {
            lastNames = CSVFileTools.readFileFromInputStream("namep_last_name_idf.csv",new ClassPathResource("namep_last_name_idf.csv").getInputStream());
            lastNameKBSize = lastNames.size();
            lastNameMaxCount = getLastNameMaxCount(0);
        }
        increaseLastNameCountIdx();;
        if (firstNameIdx == firstNameKBSize)
            return null; //we've finished iterating over all permutations!

        String [] sentence;
        if (firstNameCountIdx < firstNameMaxCount / 3)
        {
            span[0] = new Span(0,2,"Name");
            sentence = partialName;
            sentence[0] = (String)firstNames.get(firstNameIdx).get("first_name");
            sentence[1] = (String)lastNames.get(lastNameIdx).get("last_name");
        }
        else
        {
            span[0] = new Span(0,3,"name");
            sentence = fullName;
            sentence[0] = (String)firstNames.get(firstNameIdx).get("first_name");
            sentence[2] = (String)lastNames.get(lastNameIdx).get("last_name");
            if (firstNameCountIdx < 2*firstNameCountIdx/3) {
                sentence[1] = (String)firstNames.get(middleNameIdx).get("first_name");
            }
            else {
                sentence[1] = ((String)firstNames.get(middleNameIdx).get("first_name")).substring(0,1) + ".";
            }
        }

        return new NameSample(sentence,span,true);
    }

    @Override
    public void reset() throws IOException, UnsupportedOperationException {
        firstNameIdx = 0;
        firstNameCountIdx = 0;
        middleNameIdx = 0;
        middleNameCountIdx = 0;
        lastNameIdx = 0;
        lastNameCountIdx = 0;

        firstNameMaxCount = 0;
        middleNameMaxCount = 0;
        lastNameMaxCount = 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void close() throws IOException {
        reset();
        firstNames = null;
        lastNames = null;
    }
}
```

And

```
TokenNameFinderModel model = NameFinderME.train("en","person",new OpenNLPNameStream(),TrainingParameters.defaultParams(),new TokenNameFinderFactory());
        model.serialize(new FileOutputStream("trainedNames.bin",false));
```

I get the following error after a few minutes of running:

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded

    at opennlp.tools.util.featuregen.WindowFeatureGenerator.createFeatures(WindowFeatureGenerator.java:112)
    at opennlp.tools.util.featuregen.AggregatedFeatureGenerator.createFeatures(AggregatedFeatureGenerator.java:79)
    at opennlp.tools.util.featuregen.CachedFeatureGenerator.createFeatures(CachedFeatureGenerator.java:69)
    at opennlp.tools.namefind.DefaultNameContextGenerator.getContext(DefaultNameContextGenerator.java:118)
    at opennlp.tools.namefind.DefaultNameContextGenerator.getContext(DefaultNameContextGenerator.java:37)
    at opennlp.tools.namefind.NameFinderEventStream.generateEvents(NameFinderEventStream.java:113)
    at opennlp.tools.namefind.NameFinderEventStream.createEvents(NameFinderEventStream.java:137)
    at opennlp.tools.namefind.NameFinderEventStream.createEvents(NameFinderEventStream.java:36)
    at opennlp.tools.util.AbstractEventStream.read(AbstractEventStream.java:62)
    at opennlp.tools.util.AbstractEventStream.read(AbstractEventStream.java:27)
    at opennlp.tools.util.AbstractObjectStream.read(AbstractObjectStream.java:32)
    at opennlp.tools.ml.model.HashSumEventStream.read(HashSumEventStream.java:46)
    at opennlp.tools.ml.model.HashSumEventStream.read(HashSumEventStream.java:29)
    at opennlp.tools.ml.model.TwoPassDataIndexer.computeEventCounts(TwoPassDataIndexer.java:130)
    at opennlp.tools.ml.model.TwoPassDataIndexer.<init>(TwoPassDataIndexer.java:83)
    at opennlp.tools.ml.AbstractEventTrainer.getDataIndexer(AbstractEventTrainer.java:74)
    at opennlp.tools.ml.AbstractEventTrainer.train(AbstractEventTrainer.java:91)
    at opennlp.tools.namefind.NameFinderME.train(NameFinderME.java:337)
```

Edit: After increasing the memory of the JVM to 8GB, I still don't get past the first 2 million last names, but now the Exception is:

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

    at java.util.HashMap.resize(HashMap.java:703)
    at java.util.HashMap.putVal(HashMap.java:662)
    at java.util.HashMap.put(HashMap.java:611)
    at opennlp.tools.ml.model.AbstractDataIndexer.update(AbstractDataIndexer.java:141)
    at opennlp.tools.ml.model.TwoPassDataIndexer.computeEventCounts(TwoPassDataIndexer.java:134)
    at opennlp.tools.ml.model.TwoPassDataIndexer.<init>(TwoPassDataIndexer.java:83)
    at opennlp.tools.ml.AbstractEventTrainer.getDataIndexer(AbstractEventTrainer.java:74)
    at opennlp.tools.ml.AbstractEventTrainer.train(AbstractEventTrainer.java:91)
    at opennlp.tools.namefind.NameFinderME.train(NameFinderME.java:337)
```

It seems the problem stems from the fact I'm creating a new NameSample along with new Spans and Strings at every read call... But I can't reuse Spans or NameSamples, since they're immutables.

Should I just write my own language model, is there a better Java library for doing this sort of thing (I'm only interested in getting the probability the extracted text is actually a name) are there parameters I should tweak for the model I'm training?

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: What memory settings do you use? How about just giving your JVM more memory using the `-Xmx` flag?

Comment: @haraldK Increased it to 8GB, Now the error is a bit different: Java heap space error while trying to resize HashMap during AbstractDataIndexer.update...

Comment: @Mr.WorshipMe  writing your own language model would be better!

Comment: @AIaye Thanks, I wrote it today :)